# How do you set a file on a webserver to allow auto overwrite capability

Tags: ip, ftp, overwrite

I have a Foscam IPCam that snaps images every 30 minutes and will auto upload them through FTP to my website. I specify the name so it should copy over an existing image and replace it with the most current image. The problem is it adds a "_1" to the existing file name so it doesn't display on the web page. I've found FTP programs that work with USB webcams that overwrite but nothing that works with an IP cam. Is there a setting on the file permissions that will default to overwrite?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there a song on the camera itself as it's probably checking first if the file exists and appending the number if it already exists... This is not normally FTP behaviour (to work out what to rename an existing file).

Comment: *setting lol...

Answer (score 1):

Just finally answered my own question. The FTP does overwrite the file but it renames the first file to 1 before it uploads the file. You have to change the image on the site to match what the file will be named and then the (1) will be overwritten each time.